# Standardization with Interface in .Net

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have a weird question about OOP and interfaces which messed up my mind while trying to find best design.

There are two different classes which make same work (for example sending message) at different environments. These two environments use different parameters to define recipient; one is using mail address and the other one is using user name. 
So both the classes have same but slightly different methods for sending message.

**MessageSenderViaMailManager.cs**

```
public bool SendMessage(string recipientMailAddress, string message) {
..
}
```

**MessageSenderViaUsernameManager.cs**

```
public bool SendMessage(string recipientUserName, string message) {
..
}
```

There are other similar methods in both classes, responsible for same work but may require different parameters.
To make usable these managers with an interface, i created one which name is **IMessageSenderManager** and contains a definition like this.

```
public bool SendMessage(string recipientUserName, string recipientMailAddress, string message);
```

So both SendMessage methods in my classes were changed to this:

```
public bool SendMessage(string recipientUserName,string recipientMailAddress, string message) {
 ..
}
```

With this new SendMessage method, i can use appropriate parameter to use as recipient (mail address or username). This seems ok, but implemantation looks like weird. Because i have to send all parameters, without knowing which will be used at runtime while coding. For example:

```
// Sending message via username implementation
string userName = GetUserNameFromSomeWhere();
string mailAddress = GetUserMailFromSomeWhere();
IMessageSenderManager manager = MessageSenderFactory();
manager.SendManager(userName, mailAddress, "This messaged sent by your user name");
```

Like code above, sending message by mail address looks similar.

In my opinion this is not a good design so i started to think for a better solution. Bacause if i want to implement another MessageSender provider which uses different descriptor for recipient, i have to add another parameter to my interface, so to all classes. 
I thought, i could change two recipient parameters with one general recipient parameter and send appropriate value for context. But i am trying to use this in dynamic enviroment and the way (via user name or mail) will be determined in runtime, so i couldn't use this.

I am planing to make this, a flexible library which can be used decoupled or unit test friendly for other developers and i don't want to confuse them with meaningless parameters or with bad design.

Is there any better design for a situation like this?

**EDIT:**

Actually by my mistake, i forgot very big and important part of my question, i am sorry for this. 
As you can see from answers there are some alternatives to solve my first problem which described above. But then?
I mentioned in code, interface is returned from **MessageSenderFactory()** method but i don't know which message sender manager returned. So i have two options,

1. Write if condition to check which manager is returned from method and send mandatory parameters for that manager with proper values and send others empty.
2. Send all parameters with proper values regardless of manager, so both of them can work without problem. But in future, if another manager is added than i will need to send extra parameters for that manager, everytime.
3. Is there another way which i couldn't think yet?

Also other methods than SendMessage may require different parameters according to manager which is unknown at runtime. For example:

**MessageSenderViaMailManager**'s **AddContact** method may require parameters below:

- Contact Name
- Contact Mail
- Contact Phone Number
- Contact MailType (rich, plain)

or **MessageSenderViaUserNameManager**'s **AddContact** method may require parameters below:

- Contact Name
- Contact Mail
- Contact User Name
- Contact Message Platform (Twitter, facebook, vs)
- Contact Sender Name

So this makes everything very complicated. 
How my IMessageSenderManger's AddMethod should be? Should it contain all parameters? Should i overload it? Or should i put common parameters in method and make other parameters which vary by manager anonymous (like HtmlHelper in MVC)

I know this is question isn't very solid and i am not good at describing in English.

**GitHub EDIT:**

I created a small example and uploaded to github, i hope this can help me to explain my question better
https://github.com/bahadirarslan/InterfaceDesign

Comment: How about passing a `User` object to the `SendMessage` method?

Comment: How does the implementation looks like for `SendMessage`?

Comment: For starters, since you ask "what is the best", your question is "opinion based", so I'm voting to close, and I'm not adding an answer. Also, this is a very localized question, it will hardly help future readers, as even the title is too vague to help anyone find that with search query or even google. That's why a close-vote. However, I can see your problem and I'll try to repond in comments.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I disagree, How this is opinion based? OP is here with a specific problem to solve. Though I agree that question title is poorly written, if changed. it will help future readers for sure.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that all I wanted to write, can be squashed to what KlausByskovPedersen already said: change the `string email`/`string username` so that the SendMessage takes a `User` object as the target, and the underlying SendMessage implementation will be able to pick whatever it needs from the User object. If you don't have such thing as User, pass UserID (assuming your users have it)..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: This question is well written, is detailed, and asks for reasonable things. However, it bears a questions like "In my opinion this is not a good design so i started to think for a better solution." + "Is there any better design for a situation like this?" which calls for opinions and discussions. There are many ways to solve this problem, even if some ways are more widely used and some are less, still, for me, it's almost a definition of opinion-based and discussion-inducing question.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly comments. It may contain some misunderstanding because of my english, espacially in title, i couldn't find better one. Of course i am not looking for a magical solution, i am looking for another opinion and approach to the problem. Accepting a class instead of string parameters as arguments is the first thing that i think; but i couldn't be sure is this a better implementation.

Comment: Also if you suggest better title, i will be glad to alter.

Comment: I had updated the question and added github link of my example. I hope this helps me to explain my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:*** *Former answer redacted for clarity.*

I've changed the code to utilize your structure.

```
public static class MessageSenderManagerFactory
{
  public static IMessageSenderManager Create(IRecipient recipient)
  {
    return new MessageSenderManager { Recipient = recipient };
  }
}

public interface IMessageSenderManager
{
  public IRecipient Recipient { get; set; }
  bool SendMessage(string message);
}

public class MessageSenderManager : IMessageSenderManager
{
  public IRecipient Recipient { get; set; }

  public bool SendMessage(string message)
  {
    // At this point you construct the actual message and sending mechanism.
    // You'll have all the information you need in the TheUser property of Recipient.
    // The following is an example how this can be implemented but since you have not
    // provided what information you need to send or HOW you send the message I can't
    // be more specific.

    var messageToSend = new Message(message);
    messageToSend.Address = Recipient.GetRecipientAddress();

    messageToSend.Send();
  }
}

public interface IRecipient
{
  public string GetRecipientAddress();
}

public abstract class RecipientBase
{
  public User TheUser { get; set; }
  private RecipientBase() { }
  protected RecipientBase(string userId) { TheUser = FindUserById(userId); }
}

public class MailRecipient : RecipientBase, IRecipient
{
  public MailRecipient(string userId) : base(userId) { }
  public string GetRecipientAddress() { return TheUser.Mail; }
}

public class UserNameRecipient : RecipientBase, IRecipient
{
  public UserNameRecipient(string userId) : base(userId) { }
  public string GetRecipientAddress() { return TheUser.UserName; }
}
```

So when you have the user id you use ***one*** *of the following* lines depending the type of recipient (as you do with switch-case in your git example):

```
var manager = MessageSenderManagerFactory.Create(new MailRecipient(userId));
var manager = MessageSenderManagerFactory.Create(new UserNameRecipient(userId));
```

The logic of which type of `Recipient` to use should not be based on the users id. There should be a flag or setting in the database or `User` object that specifies this.

Then to send the message:

```
manager.SendMessage(message);
```

***Disclaimer:*** *Code not tested.*

Comment: I was writing exactly same thing like this +1

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, this is approach seems fine, too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i updated question, could you look it again?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: If you look at my example you'll see there is only one `SendMessage` method. In that you can check which actual class it is that's implementing the interface. You do it with the keyword `is`. I.e. `if (Recipient is EmailRecipient) ...`

Comment: @SaniHuttunen i am gratefull for your answer. But if i don't know which data i have to send at runtime. I read some values from database and send them to the factory, then it returns me an interface. Yes i can check values with if but i don't want to use if clause, if it is possible.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Again: We don't have enough information to give you a concrete example. You'll have to provide more specific information. You say you get values from a database. What values? Email? Username? If **you** get the values from the database **you** must know what it is. Right?

Comment: @SaniHuttunen May I tell you're tagging the wrong person twice :)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen i am creating a real example on github or dotnet fiddle for better explanation.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen i had created an example and uploaded to github. https://github.com/bahadirarslan/InterfaceDesign

Comment: Thanks for your new answer. So, at the end there is no way to determine right recipient other than if condition. Of course in real life they are not based on user Id's but they are dependent to users. I think i found another way, if it works i will publish from here. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Why not have you interface as follows:

```
public bool SendMessage(string recipient, string message) {
..
}
```

Then within the logic of each class you add some code to validate the recipient information, so for example you implementation that expects an e-mail address, add validation to check what you are passed is a valid e-mail address.
Then in your implementation that expects a username, validate you can find the user.

You could always implement that checking in your factory so it knows which class to create.

Comment: thanks for answer but i can not accept this. because this doesn't solve anything; besides it will cause more problems in the future if another way of sending message will need to add. also i don't want to check string value is email or else.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `class MailMessage` which contained a recipients property. Then on that `MailMessage` class have 2 overloads of an `AddRecipient` method. One for each of the ways you are adding recipients.

Comment: this solution may be considered. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Design is always the result of a specific set of requirements. It's no different with OO: there are virtually infinite ways to implement a library that can send e-mails in various circumstances. Which design/implementation is good depends entirely on your situation. So asking 'what design is best' is meaningless unless you reveal some more details about your requirements:

*Why do you want/need to redesign what you have already implemented?*

Nonetheless, I agree that tha abstraction you have chosen (one method with multiple parameters, which are optional or mutual exclusive depending on which information the client had), seems poor. Generally, methods and classes are best designed simply and straightforward, such that every parameter makes sense. In other words: your first design with two different classes is, IMHO, better than your second one, because it better aligns with the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).